# CentOS5 & OpenSSH not recognizing 'HashKnownHosts' and 'StrictHostKeyChecking' directives in sshd_config

Tags: ssh, configuration, centos5, known-hosts

I am running the latest build of OpenSSH (4.3p2) from CentOS 5. When I attempt to start the server with `/etc/init.d/sshd start`, this is the output from bash:

> ```
> Starting sshd: 
>    /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 130: Bad configuration option: HashKnownHosts
>    /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 134: Bad configuration option: StrictHostKeyChecking
>    /etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
> ```

My man page for sshd indicates that it supports a hashed known_hosts file, but the man page I have for sshd_config does not mention either of these directives.

Are **HashKnownHosts** and **StrictHostKeyChecking** included in the RHEL / CentOS maintained version of OpenSSH?

If not, what work-arounds are available to me? Can I safely install the newest stable version of OpenSSH from source? I'm unwilling to leave known_hosts in plain-text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try /etc/ssh/ssh_config instead of sshd config.  These settings seem to be for the ssh client, not the daemon.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I was simply glancing over the missing 'd' when I searched the documentation. :p